# How to save Java path on Mac OS Sierra Terminal

Tags: java, macos, terminal

I have set the below path and do not know how to save the text to exit the bash profile below. What do I press on the keyboard to allow me enter (wq) in other to save the file.

```
export JAVA_HOME=$(/usr/libexec/java_home)
PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME
export M2_HOME=/Users/tutu/Downloads/apache-maven-3.5.2 
export PATH=$PATH:$M2_HOME/bin
```

Comment: if you are using vi, it is ESC.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presuming you are using `vi` or `vim`

Hit your Esc key

then you just type

```
:wq
```

or

```
:x
```